# Find the sum of specific elements from an interval (simulation required)

Tags: r, vector, sum, element

I would like to do some simulation with for loop/while loop/ifelse (or any other method) to get the total number of elements from a specific interval. Thank you in advance if you can help me! i've been struggling a lot for this question!

There must have a difference of more than 1 in between the elements of the second set of five numbers and the elements of the first set of five numbers, then also a difference of more than 1 for the elements of the third set of five numbers and elements of second set of five numbers, and so on for the following set of five numbers

Code to get the interval:

```
set.seed(50) 
a=sort(runif(10,0,1)) 
b=sort(runif(30,1,4)) 
total=c(a,b)
```

for example, from the interval in the picture, `total[1]`, `total[2]`, `total[3]`, `total[4]` and `total[5]` are my first five numbers, then my next 5 numbers must have a difference of more than one compared with the first 5 numbers. Hence, the next 5 numbers must be `total[11]`, `total[12]`, `total[13]`, `total[14]`, `total[15]`. then the 11th number must be `total[27]` because `total[27]` is the first element that has a difference of more than one compared with `total[11]`.

May I know whether there are any ways to get the sum of the elements of `total[1]`, `total[2]`, `total[3]`, `total[4]` and `total[5]`, `total[11]`, `total[12]`,...,`total[27]`,....? without counting manually

[image]

Comment: You write that the difference between the numbers must be more than one but the 5th number in total is 0.43765986 and the 11th is 1.22237104. The difference is less than one. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I might not have explained clearly here. The difference must be more than one for the 1st element of the 1st set of five numbers and the the 1st element of the 2nd set of 5 numbers. So the 5th element of the 1st set of five numbers must have a difference of more than one with the 5th element of 2nd set of five numbers. Therefore, the 5th number must be compared with the 15th element here (in the interval) instead of the 11th element in the interval. The 11th element is only compared to the 1st element, then 12th compared with the 2nd and so on...

Comment: i'll try to digest and learn it slowly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with an `for()` loop. First we create a dataframe with needed number of rows and columns. Then, inside the for loop we get a set of five numbers and compare them to the last set. After the for loop we keep only rows of the dataframe which are of interest, e.g. with the sets being a difference of one or more.

```
n_rows <- length(total)-4
df <- data.frame(ind= rep(NA, n_rows), keep= rep(FALSE, n_rows))
df$ind[1] <- 1; df$keep[1] <- TRUE
last_ind <- 1

for(i in 2:n_rows){
  set_i <- total[i:(i+4)]
  last_set <- total[last_ind:(last_ind+4)]


  df$ind[i] <- i
  df$keep[i] <- all(set_i - last_set >= 1)
  last_ind <- df$ind[max(which(df$keep))]

}

df <- df[df$keep, ]

df
   ind keep
1    1 TRUE
11  11 TRUE
27  27 TRUE
```